# Macro won't select value in ComboBox

Tags: combobox, macros

I'm working on an asset management database for my company. Part of its function will be to track where loaner computers go.  So I have built a 2 level navigation form (`NavigationFRM`).

What I would like to happen is when you select a tab on the the top of the form, it automatically fills in information on the sub form of the form.  To do this:

1. I have created an embedded macro that will select a value on a hidden combo box;
2. After update event on the combo box will fill out information on the form.

The problem is the macro works and sets the value of the combo box, but that's it.  It doesn't trigger a change of info in the other fields.

I'm told that I have to a re-query on the combo box, but I can't access it as it's on a sub form.  If I could get the macro to access that combo box and re-query the data, then I could move on.

```
Main form = NavigationFRM
sub navigation form = LoanerFRM1 
Combo box = LoanerSelectCMBO
```

Please let me know of any other info you may need to assist.

Comment: Corrected grammar and formatting

Comment: Yeah, what software are we talking about? Use the proper tags. And don't use the macros tag, that is for something else.

Comment: I am using access 2013